# How to place geom_text labels in the correct position with a grouped box plot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

In this scenario I have added a grouping variable in the iris dataframe. I wish to make a boxplot of Sepal.Length by Species and filled by the grouping variable with the outliers identified with a label. This all works but when I try to label the outlier with geom_text, they do now print with the grouped position but instead in the center. It seems geom_text is not inheriting the global aes() but I don't know why.

code:

> ```
> library(tidyverse)
> # function to id outlier
> is_outlier <- function(x) {
>   return(x < quantile(x, 0.25) - 1.5 * IQR(x) | x > quantile(x, 0.75) + 1.5 * IQR(x))
> }
>
> # make a grouping variable
> iris$group <- sample(1:3, nrow(iris),replace = T)
>
> # make a outlier variable
> iris <- 
>   iris %>%
>   group_by(Species, group) %>%
>   mutate(outlier = ifelse(is_outlier(Sepal.Length), Sepal.Length, as.numeric(NA)))
> iris$outlier
>
> # graph
> iris %>%
>   ggplot(aes(x = Species,y = Sepal.Length, fill = factor(group))) +
>   geom_boxplot() +
>   geom_text(aes(label = outlier))
> ```

labels are in the center rather than over their respective box. What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to dodging in the boxplot once you have the group. Use [`position_dodge`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_dodge.html) to explicitly control it. You may want to experiment with the `hjust` and `vjust` arguments in `geom_text` to avoid plotting over the point.

```
iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Species,y = Sepal.Length, fill = factor(group))) +
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = outlier), position = position_dodge(width = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: yeah, that was it. Thanks